# Unsure of PWM frequency for HobbyWing Platinum-60A Brushless ESC

Tags: arduino, stm32, pwm, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I want to program this ESC [HobbyWing Platinum-60A Brushless ESC](https://p11.secure.hostingprod.com/@hobbypartz.com/ssl/ibuyrc/manual/07E-107-PLATINUM.pdf) (Manual)

I want to first try it using Arduino's Servo Library and then using STM32F4. 
From its manual:
[image]

It says that it requires PWM of 12KHz or 8 KHz. Are these the correct values? I'm unsure because most tutorial on how to program an ESC uses 50Hz-400Hz.

Comment: 50-400Hz is the frequency of the sinusoidal currents for industrial induction motors. It is not even the PWM switching frequency used by the drives to generate those sinusoidal waveforms

Comment: Maybe I misread, but here one where I got the information. It's from Arduino's forum https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=581467.0

Comment: You are probably confusing the *command pulse* with the motor PWM frequency.  The two have no direct timing relationship, one is information, the other is drive.  That said, this is a question about the *usage* of a product, and thus off topic here.  Generally your best resource for something like this is going to be RC hobby sites, especially sites where people re-flash these with custom firmware.

Comment: "You are probably confusing the command pulse with the motor PWM frequency." I confirm it, I believe you're right.  I shouldn't have posted it for a spesific device since it's actually general for ESCs. I'll accept your answer. I'm ok if a moderator close it. Or if it gets many thumb downs I'll close it.

Comment: Yeah 50Hz-400Hz there is frequency of the command pulse.